# Getting too many child nodes and cant get attributes

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have a simple XML, and I want to get the attributes. There are a few examples on the web, but I still dont understand why I get 17 when I see only 4. I even try to count locations where I think text could be, but still I don't get that number unless is the length of the output . Which leads me to not know how to get the attribute name of all Tag3.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag1 xmlns="something">
    <xxxxxx-Set>
        <tag3 Name="a"/>
        <tag3 Name="b"/>
        <tag3 Name="c"/>
        <tag3 Name="d"/>
    </xxxxxx-Set>
    <tagB>
        <tag3 Name="a"/>
        <tag3 Name="b"/>
        <tag3 Name="c"/>
        <tag3 Name="d"/>
    </tagB>
</tag1>
```

This is my java code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


public class ParseXML {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            File test= new File("test.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(test);

            NodeList tagAs= doc.getElementsByTagName("xxxxxx-Set").item(0).getChildNodes(); //should be all the tag3 elements?

            for(int i = 0; i < tagAs.getLength(); i++)    {
                System.out.println(tagAs);
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: adding .getAttributes().getNamedItem("Name").getNodeValue() to the print statement gives me null exception.
And the output is:

```
[xxxxxx-Set: null]
0
[xxxxxx-Set: null]
1
...
[xxxxxx-Set: null]
16
```

Comment: Why do you have so many "<tag3 />" in your xml?

Comment: replace `System.out.println(tagAs);` to `System.out.println(tagAs.item(i).getNodeName());` and find out some interesting about nodes in Xml.

Comment: Sorry about those extra <tag3/> was a mistake. or extra items before. I had seen that about text elements, which i suppose its what would go inside of <tag3> here <tag3/>. Is there a way around it, or just print the odd ones?

Comment: Is there a way around the text tags, reason i dont get all tag3, but first i get xxxxxx-Setis because I use a tag3 later on the document that i dont want to get here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to take all your `Name` attributes (it's better to name them with lower case), use next approach:

```
Element xSet = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("xxxxxx-Set").item(0);
NodeList xSetTags = xSet.getElementsByTagName("tag3");

for(int i = 0; i < xSetTags.getLength(); i++)    {
    Element tag3 = (Element) xSetTags.item(i);
    System.out.println(tag3.getAttribute("Name"));
}
```

I made it using `org.w3c.dom.Element` class. It's not the best idea to work with [`org.w3c.dom.Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html), because this class represents not only xml elements, but attributes, comments and other too. Look documentation to get difference between `Node` and `Element` classes.